# Create unique dictionaries for two keys in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, unique

I am getting a list of dictionaries in the following format from an API, :

eg.

```
xlist =[
    { "id":1, "day":2, name:"abc", ... },
    { "id":1, "day":3, name:"abc", ... },
    { "id":1, "day":2, name:"xyz", ... },
    { "id":1, "day":3, name:"xyz", ... },...
  ]
```

So, to store/optimize the queries in to the DB I have to convert them in this format.

- What is efficient or other way to generate following structure?

  ```
  unique_xlist =[
    { "id":1, "day":2, name:["abc", "xyz"], ... },
    { "id":1, "day":3, name:["abc", "xyz"], ... },
  ]
  ```

What I am doing :

```
 names = list(set([ v['name'] for v in xlist])) #-- GET UNIQUE NAMES
 templist =  [{k:(names if k == 'name' else v) \
           for k, v in obj.items()} for obj in xlist] #-- Append Unique names
 unique_xlist= {v['day']:v for v in templist}.values() #- find unique dicts
```

I don't think this is very efficient, am using 3 loops just to find unique dicts by day.

Comment: You you only have to collect different `name`s?

Comment: @Jasper - Yes, also but there could be multiple keys like name, suppose email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

xlist.sort(key=lambda x: (x["id"], x["day"], x["name"]))  # or use sorted()
unique_xlist = []

for k, g in groupby(xlist, lambda x: (x["id"], x["day"])):
    unique_xlist.append({"id": k[0], "day": k[1], "name": [i["name"] for i in g]})
```

Comment: nice functional answer +1. not sure you want to give that to a beginner though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the values that makes an item unique as keys to a dictionary:

```
grouped = {}
for x in xlist:
    key = (x['id'], x['day'])
    try:
        grouped[key]['name'].append(x['name'])
    except KeyError:
        grouped[key] = x
        grouped[key]['name'] = [x['name']]
```

You can listify this again afterwards if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This is bit tricky to understand me (newbie to python). Could you please explain how can I use this code for different other keys also. suppose `name` and `email`.

Comment: What do you want to do with these other keys? What this does is group items by `id` and `day`, and it converts the `name` into a list to append further names to. – The first time you encounter a unique value (an id+day not encountered before) `grouped[key]` will throw a `KeyError` and that part of the code is executed. The next time you encounter the same id+day combination the name is simply appended to the `name` list.

Comment: First try to understand the code and try to solve the modified problem yourself, this is a very nice exercise for mastering python `dict`s

Comment: @deceze - Thanks, I got you. I can now modify the code. I just have to save those in to the DB.